# In Android how to get CheckBox onCheckedChanged from other activity

Tags: android

the first one - 16.1 Example A Preferences

[Android tutorial](Http://www.bogotobogo.com/Android/android16Preferences.html)
(sorry for the link)

Cant for the love of android not get this to work
I want to click that CheckBox witch is connected to the autosave PreferenceActivity
and at the same time clicking it I want to fire an event to a method in the Activity that started the PreferenceActivity. There i will start a service.

`` Sigh hope you understand the probl.

Comment: Get a onCheckedChanged event from PreferenceActivity class
witch has this special xml file 
<PreferenceScreen android:key="checkbox1"

It cant be addressed like this from my Activity
checkBox1(new OnCheckedChangeListener()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()` to be notified of when the user changes that preference. In the listener, start your service.

Be sure to have a plan for stopping that service, as leaving it running indefinitely will generally be unacceptable to the user.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply it really helps.
Yes i know about the Service Ghost. Was thinking i use this
registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() to give user a chance to turn it off/on. 
Thanks again and have a bugg-free new year